# psycopg2 "select for update"

Tags: python, psycopg2, select-for-update

I'm using psycopg2 for using Postgresql with Python, but I am not sure how to get a "select for update" query to work with it. I can also use something besides psycopg2. How can a postgresql select for update query be created with Python?

Answer (score 2):

psycopg2 is just executing the sql in the string that you send to the execute method. you just put select for update in your query like you would anywhere else.

```
cursor.execute("""select * from some_table for update""")
```